# General rule for predicting Kessler syndrome

Tags: debris, risk-management, prediction, kessler-syndrome

Let's say that we have a gradient for density of orbiting bodies by altitude. And we also have their relative size dispersion.

Is there any general rule (or preferably a neat formula) for predicting the possibility of Kessler syndrome? Or are these calculations generally done on a case-by-case basis?

What role does inclination and eccentricity dispersion play in such a calculation?

Comment: Other than the ones in the [original paper](http://aquarid.physics.uwo.ca/kessler/Critical%20Density%201991.pdf) ?

Comment: Oh, wow, thanks! I had no idea it was only 4 pages long

Comment: @Krumuvecis it's always okay to post an answer to your own question in Stack Exchange. If you read through and come to an understanding that you are satisfied with, please feel free to go ahead and post it as an answer!